# Webalizer geolocation on Mac

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, geolocation, webalizer

I have installed Webalizer on Ubuntu with Synaptic Package Manager and it works just fine.

Then I installed Webalizer on Mac (10.6.2) with http://webalizer.darwinports.com/. But geolocation does not work.

I have parsed the exactly same log with Ubuntu and Mac, and Ubuntu finds 156 locations and Mac finds only one: `Unresolved/Unknown`.

[FAQ](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/faq.html) in `7b. My Server doesn't do name lookups. Will The Webalizer?` says to read [DNS.README](ftp://ftp.mrunix.net/pub/webalizer/DNS.README) to figure out how to set up geolocation. I have read it and I did not understand anything.

At [download](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/download.html) page I have found the link to [Latest Webalizer GeoDB database](ftp://ftp.mrunix.net/pub/webalizer/webalizer-geodb-latest.tgz). It's readme says I should probably just copy GeoDB.dat to /usr/share/GeoDB, but that did not help. It also says:

> The default location can be found by using the '-vV' command line switches of the Webalizer if you are unsure.

But that does not say where default location is.

Mac:

```
$ webalizer -vV
Webalizer V2.01-10 (Darwin 10.2.0) English
Copyright 1997-2001 by Bradford L. Barrett
```

Ubuntu:

```
$ webalizer -vV
Webalizer V2.01-10 (Linux 2.6.31-16-generic) locale Copyright 1997-2001 by Bradford L. Barrett
```

When I run webalizer on Ubuntu it says it is using geoip database (Mac does not even display that line):

```
$ webalizer -o report december.log
...
Using default GeoIP database
...
```

[README](ftp://ftp.mrunix.net/pub/webalizer/README) says I should use -J switch to point to geolocation database, but I guess I am doing something wrong, because it tries to use geolocation file as input file:

```
$ webalizer -o report -J /Users/zeljko/GeoDB.dat december.log
Webalizer V2.01-10 (Darwin 10.2.0) English
Using logfile /Users/zeljko/GeoDB.dat (clf)
Creating output in report
Hostname for reports is 'mac'
Reading history file... webalizer.hist
Skipping bad record (1)
...
No valid records found!
```

It behaves the same on Ubuntu if I try to use downloaded geolocation database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webalizer needs to be built with --enable-geoip for the geolocation to work - that darwinports version doesn't compile Webalizer with --enable-geoip. Ubuntu/Debian do, so that's why it works there.

You could compile it from scratch yourself and enable GeoIP

- you'll need to download/compile/install the GeoIP library from [here](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/c/GeoIP.tar.gz)
- then download the Webalizer source and rebuild it with ./configure --enable-geoip

DNS and GeoIP are two different things - that DNS.README Is just for getting basic DNS resolution working.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I have tried to build Webalizer on Mac, but it was dependency hell. I required a ton of stuff to be installed. Not worth the time. I will use it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You are using v2.01 which does not support geolocation.

Comment: Which version should I use?